# How to wrap Rich Text Area in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, slds, richtextarea, long-text-area, line-break

How do you wrap the text automatically? I have tried several approaches but none of them it works.

Data type for the Description field is: `Rich Text Area(131072)`

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(description,'\n','\\\n')}"            
                      escape="false" style="white-space:pre;"/>
```

Controller:

```
 public String Description {get;set;}
```

in the controller constructor:

```
 myobject__c = /*soql*/
 Description = myboject__c.Description__c;
```

Screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the problem is? Do you just have one super long line and need it to wrap?

Comment: I thought I explained but yes I'm looking to wrap the long line.

Comment: Try changing the `white-space` style to `pre-wrap`...

Comment: That looks like Lightning? Are you using slds-vf?

Comment: @AdrianLarson: it does work :) please post that as answer

Comment: @sfdcfox: yes i'm using slds in vf

Comment: @NickKahn Technically, the correct way to do so is via [slds-wrap](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/grid/#overview).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your `white-space` style to `pre-wrap`. Take a look at the [CSS white-space Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp):

> **normal**
>   Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary. This is default
>
> **nowrap**
>   Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a `<br>` tag is encountered
>
> **pre**
>   Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the  tag in HTML
>
> **pre-line**
>   Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
>
> **pre-wrap**
>   Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
>
> **initial**
>   Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial Play it »
>   inherit Inherits this property from its parent element. Read about inherit

Comment: Technically, the correct method is to use `slds-wrap`, explained [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/utilities/grid/#overview).